# How to turn data from database by row/column into multiple array using PHP?

Tags: php

I just want to ask one question.

How to actually retrieve the skillname, skillset from DB and put them in $objects. For example,

```
$objects = [
        'ANDROID STUDIO' => ['ANDROID STUDIO', 'JAVA'],
        'C#' => ['ANDROID STUDIO', 'JAVA', 'C#'],
    ];
```

```
Desired output: array(2) { ["C#"]=> float(0.29814239699997197) ["ANDROID STUDIO"]=> float(0.18257418583505536) }
```

So, I tried to change the $objects by retrieving them from the DB. See my code below:

```
    <?php

require_once 'recommend.php';
require_once 'content_based.php';
include('connection/connection.php');
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM SKILL SK, SKILLSET SK";
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT S.SKILL_NAME ,GROUP_CONCAT(SK.SKILLSET_NAME SEPARATOR ',') AS SKILLSET_ALL
        FROM SKILL S
        LEFT JOIN SKILLSET SK ON S.SKILL_ID = SK.SKILL_ID
        GROUP BY S.SKILL_ID, S.SKILL_NAME";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$count = 0;
$skillname = '';
$skillset ='';
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    

if ($checkrows > 0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $skillname .= $row['SKILL_NAME'];
        $skillset .= $row['SKILLSET_ALL'];
        
    }
    
        $count++;
        
}

    $objects = [
        $skillname  => [$skillset]
    ];
    

$user = ['Oracle',
'BlueJ',
'Star UML',
'Eclipse',
'Visual Basic',
'ANDROID STUDIO',
'Matlab',
'Adobe Spark',
'Jupyter Notebook',
'Java',
'C#',
'XML',
'HTML',
'Prolog',
'Java Developer'];

$engine = new ContentBasedRecommend($user, $objects);

var_dump($engine->getRecommendation());
```

This is MY result for SQL statements
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUSE9.jpg

```
What I Get: array(1) { ["ANDROID STUDIOC#"]=> float(0) }
```

content_based.php

```
<?php

class ContentBasedRecommend extends Recommend
{
    const USER_ID = '__USER__';
    protected $data;

    function __construct($user, $objects)
    {
        $this->data[self::USER_ID] = $this->processUser($user);
        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $this->processObjects($objects));
    }

    public function getRecommendation()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($this->data as $k => $v) {
            if($k !== self::USER_ID) {
                $result[$k] = $this->similarityDistance($this->data, self::USER_ID, $k);
            }
        }

        arsort($result);
        return $result;
    }

    protected function processUser($user)
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($user as $tag) {
            $result[$tag] = 1.0;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    protected function processObjects($objects)
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($objects as $object => $tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $result[$object][$tag] = 1.0    ;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you haven't shared the code within  `ContentBasedRecommend`, it's impossible to tell you why this does not work as expected

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What does `$objects` contain? Why do you use string concatenation for all skill names and sets when you want to put them into an array?

Comment: Because mysqli_fetch_array will return last row only.. thats why i use concatenation. In my database, I have two skills data. I tried to use foreach, but it returns weird output.

Comment: No it doesn't, if you use it correctly! Show us how you tried to make the array

Comment: if ($checkrows > 0)
{
 
 foreach ($result as $results)
 {
  $skillname = $results['SKILL_NAME'];
  $skillset = $results['SKILLSET_ALL'];

  //echo $skillname. "<br>";
  //echo $skillset. "<br>";
  $objects = ["$skillname" => "$skillset"];

  foreach ($objects as $index => $key){
   echo $index . " => ".$key. "\n";
  }
  
 }
 
}

Comment: If you have code to share, please edit your question and include it there. As you can see, code in comments is hard to read. Also, please explain what you think is "weird" about what it outputs.

Comment: I got the answer already as you ask me to use it correctly and I tried hehe... The solutions are I should use foreach and I got it weird because i need to push the data into multiple array and it returns duplicate into an array.